# How to retrieve hidden elements when visibility is hidden

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to retrieve hidden text when the visibiility attribute is hidden:

```
<div id = "tt52433002" class="yui-module yui-overlay yui-tt yui-overlay-hidden" style="z-index: 2; visibility: hidden;">
<div class="bd">Associated with the domain : testci20160503105556.com</div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
browser.hidden(:class, 'bd').text
```

and

```
browser.hidden(:class, 'bd').value
```

But I get this error:

```
"unable to locate element, using {:class=>"bd", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"hidden"}"
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand what do you want to receive and how. Try to explain please. I see what you have. But if the page is dynamically created what do you know? What do you need to get?

Answer (score 1):

Watir is designed to act like a user. So if a user can not see the text in an element, then Watir will not return the text of the element.

Also, the element you are looking for is a `div` not a `hidden`.

If you need the text you can do:

```
browser.div(class: 'bd').inner_html
```

which makes a JavaScript call to provide the result.

---

This works:

```
browser.div.attribute_value('id') => tt52433002
```

as does this:

```
browser.div(class: 'bd').inner_html[/testci\d{14}/] => testci20160503105556
```

Comment: I want to retrive the value associated with <div id = "tt52433002"> which is hidden. and i wanted retrive on the basis of my domain For e.g., if domain =~ /testci20160503105556/i  then id = browser.div.attribute_value('id')

Comment: Also the div's visibility is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.  The error says that Watir cannot find an element using the criteria you specified.  That means either that no such thing exists anywhere in the DOM, or that it might be inside a frame.

Since the element you want is a div, then you should be using the `.div` method to access it

```
browser.div(:class => 'bd')   #finds first matching div
```

A potential second problem could occur if that classname is not very unique.  Unless you specify an additional parameter, such as index, or perhaps a portion of the text contained by the div, you may not find the div you are looking for.  A fast debugging trick (I like to do it from IRB) is to get a collection of matching divs and check the size

```
div_count = browser.divs(:class => 'bd').size
puts "there are #{divcount} divs of class bd in the dom"
```

If the count is anything more than 1, then you likely need to change how you are selecting it to ensure you get the right one.  for example

```
browser.div(:class => 'bd', :text => /Associated with the domain/)
```

If the count is zero, then check for frames

```
frame_count = browser.frames.size
iframe_count = browser.iframes.size
```

If there are frames you will have to tell watir to look inside the frame for the div, if more than one frame then be sure you specify the right one

```
browser.frame.div(:class => 'bd')  #looks for div inside first frame
```

Once you are sure you have the right div, then you ought to be able to use a method like `.text` or as in another answer `.inner_html` to get the contents of the div.